# templateUrl not working with AngularUI-Router

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, angular-ui-router

### Can you guys explain how the flow works when url get hit? and why angular template url not working?

The question is when the **url** clicked on the browser, it might go to the **cache** for URL saved from **$stateprovider.state** and then might go to find the file as I defined like below, and then where does it go ? if they need to they might go to asp.net core controller to fetch data. Am I understanding right?

The problem I am having is .. **TemplateUrl** is not pointing to the folder in the file . I tested it with another file in a different folder but it works fine other than this file.

```
$stateProvider.state("users.index", {
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: "/users/index",
    //template:'<p>test</p>',
    controller: "userController",
    resolve: {
        viewModel: ["userService", function (userService) {
            return userService.getAllUsers();
        }]
    }
});
```

Comment: Check the network tab to of the Developer Console to see any errors. Make sure that the `<base>` tag is set properly. Are you using HTML5 mode?

Answer (score 1):

After Angular UI Router determines the correct state to activate from the URL, it gets the `templateUrl` value for that state.

First, it checks the [`$templateCache` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) to see if it has an entry for `/users/index`. If it does, it uses it and is done.

If not, it uses the [`$templateRequest` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateRequest) to request that URL from the server. Since I don't know how your server is configured, I don't know what will be returned by that URL.

Hopefully that helps you get a bit further in figuring this out.